# Fixme footnote-like marker inline, but without footnotes enabled

Tags: todonotes, marginnote, fixme

I am using Fixme with margin notes, but find that I would like to have some sort of marker inline (rather than the full note) to show where the note refers to. If I use the `footnote` option I get marker I am looking for, but I think that footnotes *and* margin notes are redundant. Is there a way to denote where the `\fxnote` exists inline, when using margin notes, without actually turning on the footnote option and having the full note inline? Ideally I would use something like **(!)** to show where the note is referring to.

What I really want is an `\hline` that points to the text position, but that's just me dreaming.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\fxsetface{margin}{\linespread{1}\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

Hello \fxnote{haha}world 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `todonotes`?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}

\begin{document}

Hello \todo{haha and hehe and hihi}world

\end{document}
```

[image]

Almost everything like colours, font size, etc can be customized and you can get a list of todos too. For details `texdoc todonotes` from terminal.

To toggle them off, put `disable` option:

```
\usepackage[textsize=footnotesize,disable]{todonotes}
```

Or put `draft` in `\documentclass[11pt,draft]{article}` and pass

```
\usepackage[textsize=footnotesize,obeyDraft]{todonotes}
```

Similarly there is `obeyFinal`. A screen shot from the manual:

[image]

Comment: Hazaa! A dream come true. Thanks. It would be nice if I can just toggle them on and off the same way `fixme` uses the `draft` and `final` arguments. A workaround I came up with that works is to comment out the package `todo` package and uncomment a temporary redefinition of the `\todo` using `\newcommand{\todo}[1]{}` to essentially ignore the notes.

Comment: @mammoth Please see the update.

Comment: That works great! Thanks! I was reviewing the manual, but unable to find the appropriate usage of `draft`. I used the documentclass obeyDraft combination to get the desired result.